# My threads are not parallel, they are serial. How to make them parallel?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am practicing multi-threading.

I create two posix threads that display a text to the screen (infinite loop), but it seem only the first thread run. I modify the program without looping, first thread prints, following is second thread. It seems that my thread are not parallel, first thread has to finish before thread two start.
How can I make them parallel?

Thanks,

hdr.h

```
#ifndef HDR_HDR_H_
#define HDR_HDR_H_
#define HDR_HDR_H_
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#endif /* HDR_HDR_H_ */
```

multithread01.c

```
#include "../hdr/myfunc.h"
pthread_mutex_t lock;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t tid01;
    pthread_t tid02;
    void * status01;
    void * status02;

    pthread_create(&tid01, NULL, PrintOut01(), NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid02, NULL, PrintOut02(), NULL);

    pthread_join(&tid01, &status01);
    pthread_join(&tid02, &status02);

    return 0;
```

}

myfunc.h

```
#ifndef HDR_MYFUNC_H_
#define HDR_MYFUNC_H_
#include "../hdr/hdr.h"
void * PrintOut01 (void);
void * PrintOut02 (void);
#endif /* HDR_MYFUNC_H_ */
```

myfunc.c

```
#include "../hdr/hdr.h"

extern pthread_mutex_t lock;

void * PrintOut01 ()
{
    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        printf ("This is thread 01\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
}

void * PrintOut02 ()
{
    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        printf ("This is thread 02\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
}
```

Comment: `pthread_create(&tid01, NULL, PrintOut01(), NULL);` compiled?

Comment: You must enable compilation warnings, your `PrintOut0n()` functions return `void *` and you return nothing form them, yet your code compiled and you didn't mention any warnings.

Comment: Always check the outcome of all relevant system calls!

Comment: Also `pthread_mutex_t lock` is used uninitialised in the code shown. Which you would have been told if you'd checked the outcome of the calls to the `pthread_mutex*()` functions.

Comment: Thanks, now I know the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you are *calling* the functions in your `pthread_create` call, you're not passing the function pointers.

Compare the incorrect

```
pthread_create(&tid01, NULL, PrintOut01(), NULL);
```

with the correct

```
pthread_create(&tid01, NULL, PrintOut01, NULL);
```

---

If you remove the loops in the functions, and create the threads like you do in the code in the question, then the `pthread_create` will use whatever you return from the functions as the pointer to the thread function, and unless you return a pointer to a function you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Even after properly passing function pointers to `pthread_create()`, the particular functions in question *have the wrong signature*.  Each should accept one argument, of type `void *`.  If they don't, then UB will arise from `pthread_create()` causing them to be called as if they did accept an argument.